# Why is pyuic4 subclassing object instead of QDialog?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, python-sip, pyuic

I am newly using PyQt4 on Ubuntu. My problem is that pyuic4 generates code that subclasses object rather than the appropriate widget class, which in this case should be QDialog.

I can import PyQt4.Qt in the python interpreter without error, and I can run the .ui python script in code that dynamically loads it using uic.loadUiType("filename.ui").

I suspect I did something wrong when installing Qt, sip, and PyQt4, but I've gone over the various instructions and can't see where I might have gone wrong. Lots of googling hasn't turned up anyone with a similar problem, so I'm asking for help.

Has anyone seen this before, or know what's going on?  I welcome suggestions as to how fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem. It is supposed to be like that.
You need to make another class and subclass from your generated class AND from `QDialog`. 
This is your generated class:

```
class Ui_Class1(object):
    ...
```

This is the second class:

```
class Class1(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Class1):
    ...
```

Now you can make changes to `Class1` and use it. Important: Since `Ui_Class1(object)` is automatically generated you should not make any changes to this class. Make all your changes to `Class1(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Class1)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm glad my configuration is correct.  I was working through a tutorial by Jonathan Gardner, https://wiki.python.org/moin/JonathanGardnerPyQtTutorial, which apparently is out of date. I guess object used to have different behavior which enabled his code to work.  It doesn't work any longer.